# Does it matter if i started training of my keras model with a big value of the loss function

Tags: python, keras, carla

working on self driving car cnn model to compute the steer with the speed by taking the pervous speed sequences.when we implemented the model the first loss is huge but it decreases.So does matter the start of the loss is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **does not**. If you are starting training your net from scratch then the network will predict pretty poorly so it's normal that the loss will be very high.